# Horizontal Circular Motion at High and Low Speeds

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, velocity

I saw a question by The Organic Chemistry Tutor.

**A 2kg ball is attached to a rope moving in a horizontal circle of radius 1.0m. Calculate the tension force if the ball is moving at 5 m/s and 20m/s**
[image]
Anyways, I’m really confused because the final answer implies that when the ball travels at a higher speed, it is closer to moving at a “true” horizontal circular motion and vice versa. This suggests that the ball is travelling at a radius less than 1.0m when it is moving at a lower speed. Doesn’t that mean that the first calculation and therefore every calculation following after is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of the rope and angle are not fixed. So, you can adjust the circle radius and speed to keep the same radius by tweaking the rope length and rotation angle.

Comment: Oh my god you're right.